# .wait() and .notifyAll() not working as intended

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a program which should instantiate n amount of threads. Their job is to draw from a deck existing of 52 distinct cards, wait until the round have been evaluated(who had the highest card) and the user has the highest card shown and then repeat until the deck is empty.

The first round runs flawless, not accounting for the wrong evaluation of the cards, but then the program just locks. Never drawing new cards.

I can't quite figure out what the problem is, but my guess is that I'm calling notifyAll() before the threads wake, causing a deadlock. Even though I'm counting the number of waiting threads and only notifying if the number of waiting threads corresponds to the number of players.

EDIT: I found out that if I debug, the code runs smoothly and as intended. But as soon as I run it, it runs as earlier described.

```
public class Deck {
Stack<Card> stack = new Stack<>();


public Deck()
{
   makeAndShuffleDeck();
}

public synchronized Card drawOneCard()
{
    Card card = stack.pop();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " is drawing " + card);
    return card;
}

public void setCardValues(int x)
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        Rank.ACE.setValue(14);
    }
    else
    {
        Rank.ACE.setValue(1);
    }
}

public void makeAndShuffleDeck()
{
    for(Suit suit : Suit.values())
    {
        for(Rank value : Rank.values())
        {
            stack.add(new Card(suit,value));
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(stack);
}

public Stack<Card> getDeck()
{
    return stack;
}
```

}

```
public class Round {
ArrayList<Thread> playersInTheRound = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Card> cardsDrawnInTheRound = new ArrayList<>();
Deck deck;
int numberOfRounds;

public Round(int nrOfPlayers, Deck deck)
{
    this.deck = deck;
    fillListWithPlayers(nrOfPlayers);
    calcNumberOfRounds();
    for(Thread p: playersInTheRound)
    {
        p.start();
    }
}

public void fillListWithPlayers(int nrOfPlayers)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        playersInTheRound.add(new Thread(new Player(deck, this)));
    }
}

public void addPlayerCards(Card card)
{
    cardsDrawnInTheRound.add(card);
}

public void calcNumberOfRounds()
{
    numberOfRounds = deck.getDeck().size()/playersInTheRound.size();
}

public void playRound()
{
    while(numberOfRounds > 0)
    {
        findWinnerOfRound();
        cardsDrawnInTheRound.clear();


        while(Player.waiting == playersInTheRound.size())
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                this.notifyAll();
            }
            Player.waiting = 0;
        }

        numberOfRounds--;
    }
}

public void findWinnerOfRound()
{
    Card highestCard = null;
    Comparator<Card> comp = (Card c1, Card c2) ->
    {
        if (c1.rank.getValue() == c2.rank.getValue())
        {
            if (c1.suit.getRank() > c2.suit.getRank())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if (c1.rank.getValue() > c2.rank.getValue())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsDrawnInTheRound.size()-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j <  cardsDrawnInTheRound.size(); j++)
        {
            if(comp.compare(cardsDrawnInTheRound.get(i), cardsDrawnInTheRound.get(j)) == -1)
            {
                highestCard = cardsDrawnInTheRound.get(j);
            }
            highestCard = cardsDrawnInTheRound.get(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cardsDrawnInTheRound);
    System.out.println("Winner: " + highestCard);
}
```

}

```
public class Player implements Runnable {
Deck deck;
Round round;
public static int waiting = 0;

public Player(Deck deck, Round round)
{
    this.deck = deck;
    this.round = round;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    Card card = deck.drawOneCard();
    synchronized (round)
    {
        try
        {
            round.addPlayerCards(card);
            waiting++;
            round.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `waiting++` might not be visible to other Threads right away or at all. You can try to declare it `volatile`.

Comment: if i do 
    public static volatile int waiting = 0;

its still the same outcome.

Comment: A guess: a deadlock condition. Have you debugged with logging? Consider doing so, and also simplifying the code so that you can post a valid [mcve] for us to test.

Comment: BTW, your threads will only draw once and complete after call to `notifyAll`. Did you intend to put `run` method body inside a `while` loop?

Comment: Deadlock condition is caused by line`synchronized (round)`. Because every player owns the same round object, only one Player object is able to enter that synchronized block and increment the waiting variable to 1.

Comment: Also, the operation `++` is not atomic. Either use an atomic object i.e. `AtomicInteger` or be sure to add locks appropriately.

Comment: The run method body is now in a while loop, so it should run the correct amount of times. The program runs as intended when debugging, but not otherwise. I really can't wrap my head around it.